# Webrtc peer to peer call not working in public network

Tags: networking, webrtc, peer

I have implement webrtc video and audio conference. But, It working if my all devices are on the same internet networks. But not working on public networks.

I have used the google stun server.

Answer (score 0):

A turn server is sometimes necessary when you want to connect on public networks. Just adding a turn server should solve the problem.

Comment: I have already added. Here is the example. But, Its only working when all devices are same router or same network.

const peerConnectionConfig = {
 'iceServers': [
   { 'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
   { 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
 ]
}

Comment: You only added stun servers there. you need TURN servers

Comment: I have already added turn server. But still it not working. Can you please tell me how to check my turn and stun server is working or not?